# Windows server 2012 data center - Determine If it is a core version

Tags: windows, server, version, server-core

I have a Windows Server 2012 data center server where I configured a web application. I can't tell whether it is a core version or not as I want to install other applications which are not compatible with core versions.

The server is fully GUI enabled but from Google I found that core versions don't have a GUI. According to the following link, I went to the regedit and found out that it is a core version but my server is fully GUI and all applications like Explorer are there.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846315(v=vs.85).aspx

Is there a way a core version may have a GUI or I am missing something? How do I tell if is a core version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd184075.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The core version "GUI" is only a command line interface.

There are a few GUI programs you can run, the complete table is provided on the link above.

You won't be able to open any window explorer whatsoever on a core version.

> Another way to test if Server Core is running is to check the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion for the value of InstallationType. If it is set to "Server Core", then the Server Core installation option is installed.

I supposed this is what you tried to do.

To make it simple, if you have a start menu bar and other windows than the command line interface as you log in to your server, this is no server core =)